# How to limit KeyDown actions frequency

Tags: c#, silverlight, keydown

i'm developing my first game in silverlight. It's something like 2D labyrinth and user's moves on canvas are based on UserControl_KeyDown event. I dont have any gameloop yet. But now i'm kinda stucked - I'd need to limit the frequency of UserControl_KeyDown event or something because i need some objects in labyrinth moving faster than player can. I suppose that i can use gameloop somehow but I really dont know how and google didn't help.. I hope you could show me the way how to do this, I'd really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the time you executed your command the last time and execute it only when the TimeSpan between now and the saved time is larger than a certain amount if time.

```
private DateTime _LastExecution = DateTime.MinValue;

public void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs ea) {
    if ( ( DateTime.Now - _LastExecution ).TotalMilliSeconds > 500 ) {
        /* do you stuff */
        _LastExecution = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sascha, thanks for reply, that sounds really smart, I'm gonna to try this.

Comment: great, i learned new feature he're on stackoverflow (i'm kinda newcomer here :) )